# jquery inform alert instead of alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently has something like this below to alert the user in a popup if login fails. Is there like a in-form(in the login page) alert to alert the user that it's failed instead of a popup alert?

```
    error: function(data, status, xhr) {
    alert("Login failed.");
}
```

Comment: Yep, look into form validation with jQuery.

Comment: Are you referring to an error message that displays on the form, rather than as a modal alert dialog?

Comment: Yes. Right now, I get a popup alert. I want a alert or message below the form(below username/password fields) or something. But this is after verifying that login/password from db don't match.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for flash messages 2 days ago and i found this one. That helped me a lot.

Normally goes to append to a `<div>` a class that will present the validation errors, but in your case this is better.
http://jsfiddle.net/BaylorRae/vwvAd/

**Notice:** It's not my work

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is still a popup solution its much prettier and I love it and use it all the time. Its just like using `alert`

http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/